# After Changing Gradle File DexArchiveBuilderException Occured

Tags: android, android-manifest

I was trying to use a new API but when I changed the dependencies error started to occur one by one.

When I add this line`implementation 'com.yandex.android:mapkit:3.0.0'` ,  this line broke.`implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02'`. Android Studio suggested me to add  `//noinspection GradleCompatible` so I added. But now my app doesn't run. 
Says:

> Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException:
>   Error while dexing.
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -2147483648
>   Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException:
>   Failed to process
>   /home/melkor/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/runtime-3.0.0.aar/fba329a4af9f160a1109c717ee93ced1/jars/classes.jar

Here is my android manifest

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.melkor.testyandex"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
repositories {
    maven {
        url "http://maven.google.com/"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.yandex.android:mapkit:3.0.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `android.enableD8=true` in your gradle.properties file.

Answer (score 0):

`'com.yandex.android:mapkit:3.0.0'` depends on support-compat and support-v4 version `27.0.0`. So, the problem probably because of the clashing libraries. Try using support library version 27.0.0 instead of `28.0.0.-rc2`:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0'
```

Be noted that version `28.0.0.-rc2` is a release candidate version, some crashes is to be expected.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I changed it but it didn't work. Exactly same problem continues.

Comment: try commenting this line : `androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'`

Comment: Same issue. I update
Android Studio to 3.3.2 
gradle to 4.10.1
gradle plugin to 3.3.2 . solved it